# How can I loop and change the elements of a list with the elements of another list that has a different range?

Tags: python

This first lines work, and i get V(i) =V+QIN(i)-QOUT(i), but when i try to do
  T(i) = (T + C(i) + TIN(i)*QIN(i)) /((C(i)+QIN(i)), how can I loop trought each C [i],

```
QOUT=[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
QIN=[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0]
TIN=[10.0,12.0,13.0, 12.0]

V=[2.0, 4.0, 5.0]

T=[10.0, 11.0, 12.0]

#4 iterations

#V(i) = V+QIN(i)-QOUT(i)

lineNum=0 
for line in range(len(QIN)):
    C = []
    for i in range(len(V)):
        C.append(V[i]+QIN[line]-QOUT[lineNum])     
    lineNum +=1

    print C 

    lineNum=0         
        for t1 in range(len(TIN)):
        Tx=[]
            for c in range(len(C)): 
                for i in range(len(T)):   
                    Tx.append((T[i]*C[c]+TIN[t1]*QIN[lineNum])/(C[c]+QIN[lineNum]))
            lineNum +=1

            print Tx
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation first; something clearly isn't right here.

Comment: You may want to break down the expressions into multiple, separate for loops as opposed to nesting them so deeply.

Comment: Thats the problem I don´t now how to separate this for loops.I have tried a lot of different things, but it doesn´t work I can´t find any examples.

Comment: And I don´t now what is wrong with my indentation.

Comment: You indent _before_ a for-loop, ubt that doesn't make sense. You should indent _afterwards_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry could not post images.
indentation problems are on lines 19,21,23,25,29 - switch special characters on in any editor and you will see them.
But real cause of problem is in reusing numlines variable, thus it rises IndexError.
Possible solution:

```
QOUT=[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
QIN=[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0]
TIN=[10.0,12.0,13.0, 12.0]

V=[2.0, 4.0, 5.0]

T=[10.0, 11.0, 12.0]

for q_in, q_out in zip(QIN, QOUT):
    C = [v + q_in - q_out for v in V]    
    print C

    lineNum=0         
    for t1 in range(len(TIN)):
        Tx=[]
        for c in range(len(C)): 
            for i in range(len(T)):   
                Tx.append((T[i]*C[c]+TIN[t1]*QIN[lineNum])/(C[c]+QIN[lineNum]))
        lineNum +=1
        print Tx
```

I assumed you really intended to use linenum in this context...

PS: for t1 in range(len(TIN)):... part need unfolding to, but I don't have spirit for this right now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
QOUT=[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0]
QIN=[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0]
TIN=[10.0,12.0,13.0, 12.0]

V=[2.0, 4.0, 5.0]

T=[10.0, 11.0, 12.0]

#4 iterations

#V(i) = V+QIN(i)-QOUT(i)

for i in range(len(QIN)):
    C = []
    for v in V:
        C.append(v + QIN[i] - QOUT[i])
    print C

lineNum = 0

for t1 in TIN:
    Tx = []
    for c in C:
        for t in T:
            Tx.append((t * c + t1 * QIN[lineNum]) / (c + QIN[lineNum]))
    lineNum += 1

    print Tx
```

If you set lineNum to 0, after incrementing it in your code in loop

```
lineNum=0 
for line in range(len(QIN)):
    C = []
    for i in range(len(V)):
        C.append(V[i]+QIN[line]-QOUT[lineNum])     
    lineNum +=1

    print C 

    lineNum=0  #here
```

i guess you you don't want to nest these loops:

```
for t1 in TIN:
Tx = []
for c in C:
    for t in T:
```

in the first one.